# How to retreive data from background thread to UI thread in aysnctask?

Tags: android, arrays, android-asynctask, android-adapter

i have fetched data from my api but i don't know how to assign this fetched data to my adapter?

Issue:

1. how to set fetched data to array defined above?
2. how to set an adapter ?

   public class FetchLists extends AsyncTask<>{

   ```
       public List<MailChimpList> listTitles = new ArrayList<>();

       @Override
       protected List<MailChimpList> doInBackground(Integer... params) {
           int count = params[0];
           int offset = params[1];

           String urlString = "https://us14.api.mailchimp.com/lists?apikey=efb918ee8791215bac4c8a3a8a77-us14"

           urlString = urlString + "&count=" + count + "&offset=" + offset;

           try {
               URL url = new URL(urlString);
               HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
               connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
               InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
               BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
               String line = reader.readLine();
               String response = "";
               while (line != null) {
                   response += line;
                   line = reader.readLine();
               }

               JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);

               JSONArray lists = object.getJSONArray("lists");

               for (int i = 0; i < lists.length(); i++) {
                   JSONObject listData = (JSONObject) lists.get(i);
                   MailChimpList mailChimpList = new MailChimpList();
                   mailChimpList.id = listData.getString("id");
                   mailChimpList.title = listData.getString("name");

                   String id = listData.getString("id");
                   String title = listData.getString("name");

                   Log.d("ashutosh","id are: "+id);
                   Log.d("ashutosh","list name are: "+title);

                   listTitles.add(mailChimpList);
               }

           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }

           return listTitles;
       }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(List<MailChimpList> mailChimpLists) {

   }
   ```

   }

Comment: you can use runnable inside you thread, as you are using Async, you can set adapter in your onPostExecute method

Comment: Check answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<MailChimpList> mailChimpLists) {
     MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(context, mailChimpLists);
     myListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

As your list is customized list you need to write a customer adapter

You can declare your ListView as global variable and it can be accessed in post execute.